# How to fetch data using Phoenix Framework?

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a server where the [Phoenix Framework](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/channels) is installed.
Now, I am trying to fetch the data sent from the server using their [client JS library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix-elixir)
But I am stuck in the middle, there is no documentation/tutorial, whatsoever how to implement it and run it on the client side.

I've been digging for the last couple of hours, but unfortunately there is almost no resources about what I am looking for.

Currently, I have an HTML/JS page in which I would like to preview the data fetched using the client library.

Comment: Are you trying to use websockets or an HTTP AJAX request?

Comment: I am trying to use websockets

Comment: You need to narrow your question quite a bit.  Your current question is analogous to "Something is wrong!  What should I do?"  Vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanics are pretty well covered in [the guides](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/channels).

When you connect to the channel, you could do something like:

```
channel = socket.channel("yourchannel", {});
channel.join().receive("ok", successFunction);
channel.on("all_users", function(users) { /* do something with users */ });
channel.push("get_all_users", {});
```

In your UserChannel:

```
def handle_in("get_all_users", payload, socket) do
  users = Repo.all(User)
  users_json = Poison.encode!(users)
  {:reply, {:ok, users_json}, socket}
end
```

Basically, your channel's "handle_in" handles requests from your client similar to how a controller would handle HTTP requests. You pattern match on the incoming request, and then reply with a result if there's a reply. If you don't need to reply back, you'd return `{:noreply, socket}` instead of `{:reply, {:ok, reply}, socket}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But I what still unclear is if I can embed the code you just used in your post above to connect to the channel in the HTML file. Also, shall I embed the .JS file (client library) ?

Comment: Knowing that I am using an API in which Phoenix server is located. What I want to do, simply using the client library to fetch the data, but I really don't know how to do so!

Comment: It might be useful to follow a step-by-step example app in a tutorial. Here's a random one I found on Google: http://codetunes.com/2015/phoenix-blog/

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with web framework conventions, the Elixir community on Slack is always eager to help newcomers. http://elixir-slackin.herokuapp.com/